# How to detect control keypress/keydown inside textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension

**Is it possible to detect `e.ctrlKey` inside a text input field? As soon as the cursor is inside a text field, I only get `keyup` events:**

[image]

The text field is a `textarea`:

[image]

The event listener is set correctly because I detect keypress events for normal letter keys, as well as keydown events when the textarea is not focused.

Comment: Add your listener with `true` in the third parameter.

Comment: @wOxxOm Dude you are an absolute legend. How do you know all this stuff?

Comment: It's just the first event phase, [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing).